# Inner elements messing up parent border color change on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a React component which is rendering a set of divs, each containing inner animated svgs. The border of the parent div should change colors when hovering anywhere above the parent div. But it is not working well, as whenever i hover over one of the inner svgs, the border changes back to what it was previously.

hoping for a simple fix!

an slice out of the code:

```
  <div class="blocks2">
     <Nav.Link style={{color:'rgba(143, 0,145,.44)',
                       transform:'translate(-12px,9px)'}}
                       href="/Clusterer">
                       Clusterer
        <div class="babyarcade" style={{top:'0px',height:'144px',borderWidth: '4px',opacity:'100%'}} >
          <div style={{transform:'translate(2px,31px)'}}>
          <img src={Datalens2} class='PaintFrame' ></img>
          <img src={Data} class='clusters'
                            style={{left:'35px', top:'49px'}}></img>
          <img src={Data} class='clusters'
                            style={{left:'55px', top:'31px', animationDelay:'.19s'}}></img>
          <img src={Data} class='clusters'
                            style={{left:'81px', top:'23px',animationDelay:'.36s'}}></img>
          </div>
        </div>
     </Nav.Link>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your code would be helpful. Give us something to start with

Comment: added a bit of code, hopefully its helpful.